# Is there any solution to get span value inside input?

Tags: javascript, html

How do i get data from Span class to output in input value? have tried any but not working..

something like this

```html
<input type="text" value="<span class='total_all_amounts'>00.00</span>">
```

i just need data from class **total_all_amounts** show in **input type**

here the javascript and codes

```
 <script>
        $('.quantity').on('input', function(){
          var parent = $(this).closest('tr');
          var totalAmt = parseInt(parent.find('.total').val());
          var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());

          parent.find('.total_amount').text(totalAmt*quantity);

          calcul_total_quatities();
        })

        function calcul_total_quatities()
        {
          var total = 0;
          $('.total_amount').each(function(){
            total += parseInt( $(this).text() );
          })
          $('.total_all_amounts').text(total);

          post_data_to_server($('.total_amount').val(),total);
        }
    </script>
```

and the codes is

```
<span class="total_amount">100</span>
<input type="hidden" class='total' value="100" />
<input type="number" class='quantity' value="0" name="qty" />
```

''.

What i need is when i increase the amount from quantity it will live show on input type `<input type="text" value=" **total amount will show here** ">`

Comment: in general, you need to use javascript. But please share us more details about what you have tried so far, or how is the span getting it's value.

Comment: If you have a span with class `total_all_amounts` that you need to get it's text and put in the input value, then you can try some jQuery like this `$("input#input-id").val($("span.total_all_amounts").text())`

Comment: Wow, that is some messed up HTML. Highly recommend you re-code the section that places `<span ...>00.00</span>` as the value of an `input`.

Comment: You are just asking a wrong solution that you've tried and not working. If you can ask your problem straightly it'll be easier to give you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is add unique IDs (to avoid looping through classes) for your `<span>` and `<input>` tags like this:

```
<div>
  <p>
    Cost: <span id ="costSpan" class="total_amount">100</span>
  </p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>
    Total: <span id ="totalSpan" class="total_amount">0</span>
  </p>
</div>

<input id="hiddenInput" type="hidden" class='total' value="" />
<input id="quantity" type="number" class='quantity' min="0" value="0" name="qty" />
```

Then use JavaScript to retrieve the inputted value from `quantity` whenever it is edited using the `input` listener, multiple the value of `quantity` with the integer parsed value of `total_amount` then assigned it to your hidden input's value which in turn, assigns it to your `span` tag like this:

```
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
var hiddenInput = document.getElementById('hiddenInput');
var costVal = document.getElementById('costSpan');
var totalVal = document.getElementById('totalSpan');

function updateVal(){
  hiddenInput.value = quantity.value * parseInt(costVal.innerHTML);
  totalVal.innerHTML = hiddenInput.value;
}

quantity.addEventListener("input", updateVal);
```

---

**jsFiddle with above code:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/vqson3cd/14/

Comment: almost.. but how do make it updating live value? i have update the question with source code

Comment: The span tag is not editable as it is so I'm not sure what do you mean by live updating here. Or do you mean the other way around where there is live updating of span tag content based on what is typed into the input box?

Comment: your code is working but what i want is example if my pricing is 100usd if the qty is 1 if qty is 2 it should show price 200usd not the qty.. sorry for disturb your..